# Generalise LDAP query for groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I use the following query to find the groups each user is a member of:

`(&(objectClass=group)(|(member=cn=UID,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au)(member=cn=UID,OU=BTLY,OU=Sites,OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au)))`

This query works and runs using the following Base DN:

`OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au`

I have few problems with the query:

- I don't like having to use the OR operator to find Service Account users and BTLY users.
- I don't want to hard-code the BTLY site, there are others, too.

Ideally, I'd just like to have the query as:

`(&(objectClass=group)(|(member=cn=UID,OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au))`

This way, I don't care whether the user account is a service account nor which site the account belongs to. Unfortunately, that query doesn't work.

Can someone please help me generalise the LDAP query? I'm a bit of a newbie, so I'm most likely missing something completely obvious!

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the reply. What you've said makes sense, but it doesn't help me, unfortunately. We're using GlassFish  (a Java app server), and have configured it to point to the local AD server. Normally, a person can tell GlassFish how to retrieve users, eg

`(&(objectCategory=user)(CN=UID))`

and GlassFish will pick up all the groups (perhaps by using the `memberOf` attribute).

This time round we're using a different AD server which hosts a different directory of users. GlassFish isn't able to retrieve the groups by itself. So, there is a field where we can give GlassFish a custom query to find groups. In this field, I've put the query I've posted which works, but is ugly and verbose.

What I'd love to be able to do is:

`(&(objectClass=group)(member=cn=UID))`

but this doesn't work.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks,
Muel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that using this technique is not possible. You would need to use wildcard here:

```
(&(objectCategory=group)(member=CN=UID,*))
```

and this is not acceptable for DN attributes (like the one stored in 'member' property):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676930(v=vs.85).aspx

My suggestion here would be: use some tool to generate 'ugly' query for you (using syntax mentioned above) and "feed" your tool with end result. Can't see any option, sorry...

Comment: Amusingly, I'd tried the wildcard yesterday without success. I also tried using a subselect, which doesn't work either. I've since read that LDAP doesn't support such queries. Thanks for the MS link, it's good to read something definitive! I'll leave this question open for just a little longer on the offchance.... :)

Answer (score 0):

I just try to reformulate your question, but it's to much text for a comment.

You are trying to find all the groups the user `CN=UID` belongs to begining from the nod `OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au`.

This can be done by retreiving the `memberOf` attribute of the user itself. The only problem (perhaps not in your case) is that the *primary group* is not in this list of DN, it's coded appart using `primaryGroupId` attribute.

so

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(CN=UID))
```

Will do the job test :

```
ldifde -f t.ldf -D "OU=MC,DC=ads,DC=myCompany,DC=com,DC=au" -r "(&(objectCategory=user)(CN=UID))" -l memberof
```

Remark : `samAccountName` or `userPrincipalName` are attributes you can rely on for uniqueness of the entry in Active-Directory, that is not the case of CN (an admin can change it)